# How to check if a golang template has all the variables available in the data variable?

Tags: go

I am trying to render a string from the  Golangs Template and populating template variables with a map.

I need to have a check as to if the all the variables are available in the map.

Expected the below piece of code to throw an error.

```
templateVariables := map[string]string {} 
tmpl := template.New("test")
tmpl, err := tmpl.Parse("Hello {{.Name}}\n")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
        return
}

buf := bytes.NewBufferString("")
err1 := tmpl.Execute(buf,s)
if err1 != nil { 
    // Expected this to be true
    log.Panic(err1)

}
fmt.print(buf.String())
```

Executing above throws no Error and the value of `buf` from fmt.print turns out to be:
`Hello <no value>`

How does one ensure that all the required variables in the map are available, if not throw an error? Is there a way to do this from templates package itself?

Answer (score 2):

> How does one ensure that all the required variables in the map are available, if not throw an error?

The [option](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Option) "missingkey=error" should do what you are looking for:

> missingkey: Control the behavior during execution if a map is indexed with a key that is not present in the map.

> "missingkey=error"
> Execution stops immediately with an error.

In your example this option can be added as follows:

```golang
tmpl := template.New("test").Option("missingkey=error")
```

Try it in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w13XC9CstDE).